# ALTER TABLE used by active queries

Tags: postgresql

I've got a simple function to hard-delete rows in a table that normally has a trigger to prevent deletions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hard_delete_events (event_ids int[]) 
    RETURNS void 

AS $$
BEGIN 

    ALTER TABLE events DISABLE TRIGGER USER;    

    DELETE FROM events e WHERE e.id = ANY($1);

    ALTER TABLE events ENABLE TRIGGER USER;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm getting an error when I run the function:

```
ERROR:  cannot ALTER TABLE "events" because it is being used by active queries in this session
```

And I know that the only session active query is running the function itself.

Any advice to handle this?

Postres 9.6

Comment: Perhaps the transaction started by the `DELETE` statement needs to be commited?

Comment: out of curiocity - if you run same in transaction instead of function - it works?..

Comment: If I first run DISABLE TRIGGER, then DELETE, it works.  If I run them in the same transaction, it also fails

Comment: is it the `AFTER` trigger?.. also is it statement level or for each row?.. in general, if you put full DDL it would be gr8

Answer (score 0):

I thought functions in PostgreSQL permitted DML, so this is a surprise to me.

I'm honestly not 100% sure this will work, but it seems like it might.  If you create a foreign data wrapper back to your server like this:

```
CREATE SERVER pgprod
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER dblink_fdw
OPTIONS (dbname 'postgres', host 'localhost', port '5432');
```

Then perhaps you can change your function to execute a FDW call to fake the database out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hard_delete_events (event_ids int[]) 
    RETURNS void 
AS $$
BEGIN 

    perform dblink_exec('pgprod',
      'ALTER TABLE events DISABLE TRIGGER USER;'
    );

    DELETE FROM events e WHERE e.id = ANY($1);

    perform dblink_exec('pgprod',
      'ALTER TABLE events ENABLE TRIGGER USER;'
    );

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Again, I'm kind of spitballing.  If you had asked me if your function would work as-is, my guess would have been "yes."